# npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED

Tags: ssl, npm

while running the command npm i, I got this error:

> npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
> npm ERR! 78530000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:312:

I tried many ways to solve this like cache clear deleting package-log.json node modules but the error doesn't go please help me with this

Answer (score 6):

```
npm cache clear --force
```

Use the above command it helped me resolve the issue

Answer (score 2):

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

this will create the node module folder and install required dependencies.

Comment: Alos add --force if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you could try doing this. Did you try clearing the cache by force and updating it.
https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-npm-integrity-checksum-failed-when-using-sha512/

Answer (score 0):

My Answer: Remove(turn off) child lock button on Admin page of local network, made a new terminal and ran `npx create-react-app [name of repo]`

Why issue happened:
I was struggling with this issue for 6 days but just figured it out. I had changed isp's to Verizon about 10 days ago and had been installing plenty of projects. I installed code from Solito (React-Native and Next.JS) when this issue began.

After calling my ISP they said the internet and router were running pure but I insisted we continued to the dashboard where I saw the child locks were enabled when they previously hadn't been.

Assumption:
The new routers must shipp from the factory enabled with child locks

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f94V7.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It helped for me:

```
npm install -g https://tls-test.npmjs.com/tls-test-1.0.0.tgz
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can work as a solution but I switched over to [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com).

In my case, `npx create-react-app my-app` was constantly throwing the `NPM Err` message. Couldn't find a solution. Then I switched to `yarn create react-app my-app` and it just worked.

Comment: Also found this: `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true` from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vn97BdYx2K8 and it sort of helped.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the MongoDB shell a few days ago. Now, I completely removed and its working and created the nextjs app successfully using "npx create-next-app@latest".

Answer (score 0):

> npm cache verify

You can use the above command it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having problem with this error, but happens to use Yarn instead of NPM, this is what worked for me:

Using the command `yarn cache clean` didn't work for me, I had to manually delete the cache directory:

```bash
rm -rf $(yarn cache dir)
# or where it is *usually* located
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Yarn
```

So you could also try to do the same for NPM errors by deleting its cache:

```bash
# where it is *usually* located
rm -rf ~/.npm
```

Tested on macOS Sonoma and Ventura.